# Stepwise irregularity of the divisor function, or does $\limsup_{n\to\infty} |d(n+1)-d(n)| = \infty$?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, divisor-counting-function

Defining $d(n):= \sum_{d|n} 1$, I know that $\liminf_{n\to\infty} d(n) = 2$, and [Wigert showed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Severin_Wigert) that $\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log(d(n))}{ \log n/\log\log n} = \log 2$ (natural logarithm). This presents a decent picture of how irregular the divisor function is, but I want to know how suddenly it jumps for adjacent values of $n$. The [Wikipedia page on the divisor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) tells us that Heath-Brown proved in 1984 that $\liminf_{n\to\infty} |d(n+1)-d(n)|= 0$. Are there results about $\limsup_{n\to\infty} |d(n+1)-d(n)|$, or the behavior of the average $\frac 1N \sum_{n=1}^N |d(n+1)-d(n)|$?

Comment: Note that Dirichlet assures us that there are infinitely many primes which are, say, one more than a multiple of the product of the first $k$ primes.  If $n+1$ is one of those primes, then $|d(n+1)-d(n)|$ is at least $2^k-2$.

Comment: @lulu oh that was fast! So now we know the limsup is indeed $\infty$, the only question left is how fast does it blow up.

Comment: Yeah, my construction certainly doesn't tell you much about average behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\omega(n)$ denote the number of distinct prime factors of $n$. A theorem of Halberstam states that for any fixed irreducible polynomial with integer coefficients $f(x)$ that is not identically a multiple of $x$ satisfies the asymptotic law

$$\sum_{p<x}\omega(f(p))\log p\sim x\log \log x$$

where $p$ runs over primes. Applying this with $f(x)=x+1$ we get that $p+1$ has on average $\log\log p$ distinct prime divisors, and hence on average $d(p+1)\geq 2^{\log \log p}=\log(p)^{\log(2)}$. Thus, we can make the gaps $|d(n+1)-d(n)|$ grow as large as we want, and at least as fast as $\log(n)^{\log(2)}$.

Comment: nice! Could you link/cite the theorem of Halberstam?

Comment: From my understanding the original paper is "On the distribution of additive number-theoretic functions". Ten years prior the special case I'm using was already known to Erdos however, so perhaps you'd consider that even more original